# Eiffel: is there a way to express a double implies clause in eiffel?

Tags: design-by-contract, eiffel

Like double bind in psychology, is there a way to tell that one expression implies another and reversely?

```
valid_last_error: attached last_error implies not attached last_success_message
valid_last_success_message: attached last_success_message implies not attached last_error
```

would be something like

```
valid_last_error: attached last_error double_binded_not attached last_success_message
```

which could be equivalent to

```
valid_last_error: attached last_error never_with attached last_success_message
```

- **T** stands for True boolean expression
- **F** for False
- **R** for Result

### implies (a, b: BOOLEAN): BOOLEAN

```
a b R
T T T
T F F
F T T
F F T
```

### and (a, b: BOOLEAN): BOOLEAN

```
a b R
T T T
T F F
F T F
F F F
```

### or (a, b: BOOLEAN): BOOLEAN

```
a b R
T T T
T F T
F T T
F F F
```

### xor (a, b: BOOLEAN): BOOLEAN

```
a b R
T T F
T F T
F T T
F F F
```

### double_implies (a, b: BOOLEAN): BOOLEAN

```
a b R
T T F
T F T
F T T
F F T
```

as a maybe more explaining example (more known) instead of writing

```
invalid_index_implies_off: index < 1 implies off
off_implies_invalid_index: off implies index < 1
```

we could write:

```
index_coherent_with_off: index < 1 never_both off
```

which would just add a function to BOOLEAN class such as

```
alias never_with, alias reversible_implies (v: like Current): like Current
    do
        if Current and v then
            Result := False
        else
            Result := True
        end
    end
```

Hope now everybody got my point... I don't know if there is such arithmetic operator.

We could extend it for a **variable number of parameters**

Answer (score 0):

The only answer for my question is to define a function in an util class like

feature -- could be in class BOOLEAN

```
double_implies, reversible_implies, never_both (a, b: BOOLEAN): BOOLEAN
        -- Into boolean class with never_with
    do
        if a and b then
            Result := False
        else
            Result := True
        end
    end
```