# Eiffel: how do I create and use an UTIL class, or "call static method from class"

Tags: createprocess, eiffel

as [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52763915/2118777) describes it, I'd like to create an UTIL class with a never_both function.

```
class
    UTIL

create
    default_create

feature -- could be in class BOOLEAN

    double_implies, reversible_implies, never_both (a, b: BOOLEAN): BOOLEAN
            -- Into boolean class with never_with
        do
            if a and b then
                Result := False
            else
                Result := True
            end
        end

end
```

When I use it

```
invariant
    never_both: {UTIL}.never_both (attached last_error, attached last_success_message)
```

the **compiler complains** about a `VUNO` error

`never_both used in the non-object call is not a class feature.`

I saw 2 notations about objects creating
  - `{UTIL}.never_both (a, b)`
  - `({UTIL}).never_both (a, b)`

**Whats the difference between them?**

**How to create an application wide (could be even world wide once if you want!) object** for the use of this UTIL if possible in Eiffel?!

I know this is a TUPLE of questions so I put them in **Bold**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a feature without creating the corresponding object, it should be marked as a `class` feature. This is done in the feature postcondition with the same keyword:

```
foo ...
    do
          ...
    ensure
        instance_free: class
        ...
    end
```

After that, the feature can be used in an objectless call `{BAR}.foo ...`.

The notation `({BAR}).qux` does not denote an objectless call. It is an object call on the target object of type `TYPE [BAR]`. The object describes the type `BAR`.